# Getting a list in return instead of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary returned by `keras_model.get_config()`. (variyed by `print(type(keras_model.get_config()))`). I am getting an error on the code line:

```
if keras_model.get_config()[0]['config']['data_format'] == 'channels_first':
```

The error indicates that the dictionary has no `0` key, which is obvious ehough:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "task1a.py", line 1204, in 
>      sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
>    File "task1a.py", line 234, in main
>      overwrite=overwrite
>    File "task1a.py", line 982, in do_testing
>      if keras_model.get_config()[0]['config']['data_format'] == >'channels_first':
>   KeyError: 0

I carried on to access via `keras_model.get_config()[keras_model.get_config().keys()[0]]` but now, I am getting a list of dictionary back instead of a dictionary as in (just note the begginning and end bracests):

```
[{'class_name': 'Conv2D', 'config': {'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'distribution': u'uniform', 'scale': 1.0, 'seed': None, 'mode': u'fan_avg'}}, 'name': u'conv2d_1', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'dtype': u'float32', 'activation': 'linear', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'filters': 32, 'padding': u'same', 'strides': (1, 1), 'dilation_rate': (1, 1), 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'batch_input_shape': (None, 40, 500, 1), 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_size': (7, 7)}}, {'class_name': 'BatchNormalization', 'config': {'beta_constraint': None, 'gamma_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'moving_mean_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'name': u'batch_normalization_1', 'epsilon': 0.001, 'trainable': True, 'moving_variance_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'beta_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'scale': True, 'axis': 1, 'gamma_constraint': None, 'gamma_regularizer': None, 'beta_regularizer': None, 'momentum': 0.99, 'center': True}}, {'class_name': 'Activation', 'config': {'activation': 'relu', 'trainable': True, 'name': u'activation_1'}}, {'class_name': 'MaxPooling2D', 'config': {'name': u'max_pooling2d_1', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'pool_size': (5, 5), 'padding': u'valid', 'strides': (5, 5)}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'rate': 0.3, 'noise_shape': None, 'trainable': True, 'seed': None, 'name': u'dropout_1'}}, {'class_name': 'Conv2D', 'config': {'kernel_constraint': None, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'distribution': u'uniform', 'scale': 1.0, 'seed': None, 'mode': u'fan_avg'}}, 'name': u'conv2d_2', 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'activation': 'linear', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'padding': u'same', 'strides': (1, 1), 'dilation_rate': (1, 1), 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'filters': 64, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_size': (7, 7)}}, {'class_name': 'BatchNormalization', 'config': {'beta_constraint': None, 'gamma_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'moving_mean_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'name': u'batch_normalization_2', 'epsilon': 0.001, 'trainable': True, 'moving_variance_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'beta_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'scale': True, 'axis': 1, 'gamma_constraint': None, 'gamma_regularizer': None, 'beta_regularizer': None, 'momentum': 0.99, 'center': True}}, {'class_name': 'Activation', 'config': {'activation': 'relu', 'trainable': True, 'name': u'activation_2'}}, {'class_name': 'MaxPooling2D', 'config': {'name': u'max_pooling2d_2', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'pool_size': (4, 100), 'padding': u'valid', 'strides': (4, 100)}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'rate': 0.3, 'noise_shape': None, 'trainable': True, 'seed': None, 'name': u'dropout_2'}}, {'class_name': 'Flatten', 'config': {'trainable': True, 'name': u'flatten_1', 'data_format': u'channels_last'}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'RandomUniform', 'config': {'maxval': 0.05, 'seed': None, 'minval': -0.05}}, 'name': u'dense_1', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'activation': 'relu', 'trainable': True, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'units': 100, 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'rate': 0.3, 'noise_shape': None, 'trainable': True, 'seed': None, 'name': u'dropout_3'}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'RandomUniform', 'config': {'maxval': 0.05, 'seed': None, 'minval': -0.05}}, 'name': u'dense_2', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'activation': 'softmax', 'trainable': True, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'units': 10, 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None}}]
```

Everything is based on the code from [DCASE2018](https://github.com/DCASE-REPO/dcase2018_baseline/tree/master/task1) and I wish to change it as little as possible in this stage. How do I access the first dictionary of that dictionary? how do I chain access these dictionaries?

By the way, I have tried `type(keras_model.get_config()['layers']` and I am still getting a list back.

edit:
adding the original `keras_model.get_config()` dictionary:

```
{'layers': [{'class_name': 'Conv2D', 'config': {'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'distribution': u'uniform', 'scale': 1.0, 'seed': None, 'mode': u'fan_avg'}}, 'name': u'conv2d_1', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'dtype': u'float32', 'activation': 'linear', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'filters': 32, 'padding': u'same', 'strides': (1, 1), 'dilation_rate': (1, 1), 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'batch_input_shape': (None, 40, 500, 1), 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_size': (7, 7)}}, {'class_name': 'BatchNormalization', 'config': {'beta_constraint': None, 'gamma_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'moving_mean_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'name': u'batch_normalization_1', 'epsilon': 0.001, 'trainable': True, 'moving_variance_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'beta_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'scale': True, 'axis': 1, 'gamma_constraint': None, 'gamma_regularizer': None, 'beta_regularizer': None, 'momentum': 0.99, 'center': True}}, {'class_name': 'Activation', 'config': {'activation': 'relu', 'trainable': True, 'name': u'activation_1'}}, {'class_name': 'MaxPooling2D', 'config': {'name': u'max_pooling2d_1', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'pool_size': (5, 5), 'padding': u'valid', 'strides': (5, 5)}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'rate': 0.3, 'noise_shape': None, 'trainable': True, 'seed': None, 'name': u'dropout_1'}}, {'class_name': 'Conv2D', 'config': {'kernel_constraint': None, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'distribution': u'uniform', 'scale': 1.0, 'seed': None, 'mode': u'fan_avg'}}, 'name': u'conv2d_2', 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'activation': 'linear', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'padding': u'same', 'strides': (1, 1), 'dilation_rate': (1, 1), 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'filters': 64, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_size': (7, 7)}}, {'class_name': 'BatchNormalization', 'config': {'beta_constraint': None, 'gamma_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'moving_mean_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'name': u'batch_normalization_2', 'epsilon': 0.001, 'trainable': True, 'moving_variance_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'beta_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'scale': True, 'axis': 1, 'gamma_constraint': None, 'gamma_regularizer': None, 'beta_regularizer': None, 'momentum': 0.99, 'center': True}}, {'class_name': 'Activation', 'config': {'activation': 'relu', 'trainable': True, 'name': u'activation_2'}}, {'class_name': 'MaxPooling2D', 'config': {'name': u'max_pooling2d_2', 'trainable': True, 'data_format': u'channels_last', 'pool_size': (4, 100), 'padding': u'valid', 'strides': (4, 100)}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'rate': 0.3, 'noise_shape': None, 'trainable': True, 'seed': None, 'name': u'dropout_2'}}, {'class_name': 'Flatten', 'config': {'trainable': True, 'name': u'flatten_1', 'data_format': u'channels_last'}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'RandomUniform', 'config': {'maxval': 0.05, 'seed': None, 'minval': -0.05}}, 'name': u'dense_1', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'activation': 'relu', 'trainable': True, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'units': 100, 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'rate': 0.3, 'noise_shape': None, 'trainable': True, 'seed': None, 'name': u'dropout_3'}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'RandomUniform', 'config': {'maxval': 0.05, 'seed': None, 'minval': -0.05}}, 'name': u'dense_2', 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'activation': 'softmax', 'trainable': True, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'units': 10, 'use_bias': True, 'activity_regularizer': None}}], 'name': u'sequential_1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. The idea is to construct a list from the dict keys. (Tested with python 3.7)

```
d = {'x': 'y'}

print(list(d.keys())[0])
```

Output:

```
x
```

Comment: I wish NOT to get a list but a dictionary.

Comment: Can you post the dict that is returned from `keras_model.get_config()` ?

Comment: OK. The config data contains a list under the 'layers' key. So `data['layers'][0]` return the first item in the list. I hope it is the one you are looking for. (Each entry contains another dict named 'config')

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.6

```
>>> dic = {'a':'b'}

>>> dic.keys()
dict_keys(['a'])

>>> dic.keys()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

This means that you cannot access the elements of a dictionary by `dic[dic.keys()[0]]`.

Please provide the dictionary keras_model.get_config()

Comment: Hi, I have added the dictionary keras_model.get_config().

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was [a difference of versions for keras](https://github.com/DCASE-REPO/dcase2018_baseline/issues/28).